# Visual Studio: how to disable smart tags in Visual Studio (or change its underline color)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-basic, vb.net

How to disable smart tags in Visual Studio (2013 Community / Basic)?
If it is impossible, how can I change the underline color (for example from red to white)?

I mean about 'smart tags' the feature that underline with red color the last typed character when I rename a variable or sub name, and if I press CTRL+(DOT) or move the mouse over the underlined char, display a little window with action Rename 'VarOld' to 'VarNew'.

(My main problem is not the sub/var rename (which is rare), but also the newly typed sub/var name: in that case the red underline is always visible under the last char while I type the for example 10 character to new sub/var name.)

Screenshot of the indicated smart tag and the color of its underline:

[image: Screenshot of the indicated smart tag and the color of its underline]

Comment: Thank you for your help!  
Just only for this I don't plan to upgrade (maybe there are similar problems in it).  
I update the question with the screenshot as you suggest!

Answer (score 0):

This is the doing of IntelliSense, which is unfortunately quite dumb.
You will also find that it also puts warnings like that into the error window.

I don't know of a way to selectively disable them is some cases but not in others.

To disable all error squiggles, go to
*Tools > Options > C++- > Advanced*,
and set under *IntelliSense* the option of "Disable Squiggles" to "True".

This would disable all red squiggles, even the useful ones.

If you would rather change the color of the squiggles to one
that doesn't irritate you, you may do so in
*Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Syntax Error*,
and set the color.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
In VB there isn't IntelliSense, so I don't disable it.
At the same time your answer, I updated my question with a screenshot, and looks on it it's not a squiggle; but its first part (under 'Var' chars) is squiggle which color can modify in 'Fonts and Colors / Text Editor / Warning'.

Comment: Your Options is different than mine. My earliest version is VS2008, where I can see in "Fonts and Colors" an entry for "Smart Tag" with a blue color. Is it useful?